# Laravel Eager Loading Pivot Table Relations

Tags: mysql, laravel, model

While working on my Chat Application , I've been looking at many posts for quite some time now, but i cannot seem to grasp how i can achieve the following:

What I have:
3 Tables:

1. clients
2. channels
3. channel_client (the pivot table)

2 Models:

1. App\Clients

   ```
   class Client extends Model
   {
       protected $table = "clients";

   public function channels() {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Channel::class);
   } ...
   ```
2. App\Channels

   ```
   class Channel extends Model
   public function clients() {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class);
   } ...
   ```

What I want to achieve:
Get the Channel, which contains Client X and Client Y and nothing else. (I have access to the client ID's via the Client Model beforehand)

I tried tinkering a bit and here is the result:

```
>>> $client = App\Client::with('channels')->whereIn('id',[1,2])->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3303
     all: [
       App\Client {#3243
         id: 1,
         name: "John",
         user_id: 1,
         created_at: "2019-08-14 12:55:19",
         updated_at: "2019-08-14 12:55:19",
         channels: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3354
           all: [
             App\Channel {#3249
               id: 1,
               name: "Web Development",
               type: null,
               created_at: "2019-08-14 12:52:32",
               updated_at: "2019-08-14 12:52:32",
               pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3362
                 client_id: 1,
                 channel_id: 1,
               },
             },
             App\Channel {#3360
               id: 3,
               name: "iOS Development",
               type: null,
               created_at: "2019-08-14 12:52:32",
               updated_at: "2019-08-14 12:52:32",
               pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3321
                 client_id: 1,
                 channel_id: 3,
               },
             },
             App\Channel {#3363
               id: 5,
               name: "Android Development",
               type: null,
               created_at: "2019-08-14 12:52:32",
               updated_at: "2019-08-14 12:52:32",
               pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3329
                 client_id: 1,
                 channel_id: 5,
               },
             },
           ],
         },
       },
       App\Client {#3283
         id: 2,
         name: "Lucy",
         user_id: 2,
         created_at: null,
         updated_at: null,
         channels: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3286
           all: [
             App\Channel {#3364
               id: 1,
               name: "Web Development",
               type: null,
               created_at: "2019-08-14 12:52:32",
               updated_at: "2019-08-14 12:52:32",
               pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3248
                 client_id: 2,
                 channel_id: 1,
               },
             },
           ],
         },
       },
     ],
   }
>>>
```

As you can see here, the channel with an ID of 1 is the mutual channel for the users, as user 1 and user 2 both have channel 1 subscribed.

I know that my query returns all users and their channels where the user id is 1 or 2, but if i turn this around and query App\Channel::with('users')... I cannot specify a where clause as i don't know what channel ID it is that is the mutual one. This is what I am trying to find out with a query.
So here is the sum up:
I would like an *Eagerloading Query* (otherwise i would use whereHas) which returns the mutual channel of my clients i specify.
Thanks a lot for reading.
I do hope you can help me understand this.
Greetings!

Edit: So judging by [This Laravel Documentation Part](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) it should work as described @Mohamed Ahmed , but when i try it out i get the following result, where it seems to have loaded all channels, but also only the clients i specified (but still all channels queried, which was not really my goal)

```
    >>> $cha = App\Channel::with(['clients' => function($q){ $q->whereIn('id',[1,2]); }])->get();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3359
     all: [
       App\Channel {#3365
         id: 1,
         name: "Web Development",
         type: null,
         created_at: "2019-08-14 12:52:32",
         updated_at: "2019-08-14 12:52:32",
         clients: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3403
           all: [
             App\Client {#3398
               id: 1,
               name: "John Doe",
               user_id: 1,
               created_at: "2019-08-14 12:55:19",
               updated_at: "2019-08-14 12:55:19",
               pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3324
                 channel_id: 1,
                 client_id: 1,
               },
             },
             App\Client {#3240
               id: 2,
               name: "Lucy",
               user_id: 2,
               created_at: null,
               updated_at: null,
               pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3372
                 channel_id: 1,
                 client_id: 2,
               },
             },
           ],
         },
       },
       App\Channel {#3325
         id: 2,
         name: "Android Development",
         type: null,
         created_at: "2019-08-14 12:52:32",
         updated_at: "2019-08-14 12:52:32",
         clients: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3268
           all: [],
         },
       },
       ... all the remaining channels here (too much code)
```

So it is partially correct. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely reverse it. But that would mean a bit on tinkering (get the pun?).

What you want to do is, access the Channel model and do `whereHas('users')`. The magic happens here:

```
$channel = App\Channel::whereHas('clients', function($q){
  $q->whereIn('id', [1,2])->get();
})->get()
```

You could try this inside a controller or something as a return value.

What this basically does is, it calls the `clients` relationship and runs conditions inside the relationship. If you have your relationships set correctly (many to many relationship with pivot table set correctly) you should have no further problem. So now the above code is taking all the channels which has the clients with id 1 & 2.

Hope this helps.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your comment. Tinkering means "php artisan tinker" and writing some code in there, the snippet i post is from tinker so i dont have to create everything and just try it out there on a whim whatever comes to my head. I will try this out asap.

Comment: Yes I know what a tinker is. I was trying to make a joke. But never mind

Comment: Oh my apologies :D it's been a long day and I kind of overread the "get the pun?" hehe, I have updated my post , please have a look at it whenever you have the time to do so and still want to continue helping me.

Comment: Wait so do you mean all the remaining channels do not have the user 1 and 2?

Comment: Exactly. Here is the thing: Only Channel 1 has the users 1 and 2, but there are multiple channels , so in the returned result it shows that channel 1 has users 1 and 2, (see # 3365) but channel 2 does not have them (the clients array is empty) which is correct. The question now is, why does channel 2 (and all the other empty ones) get returned?

Comment: Please see the updated answer. Hope this works. Let me know